# Strange jQuery .prev() behaviour

Tags: jquery

I have simple HTML code:

```
<input type='hidden' name='cat_id' value='123'/>
<a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a>
<a href='#' class='delete delete-link'>Delete</a>
```

And simple JS code:

```
$("a.delete-link").click(function() {
var id = $(this).prev($('input[name="cat_id"]')).val();
    alert(id);
});
```

Everything simple and obvious, get a value of previous input with name 'cat_id'. But it just returns an empty string (value is really defined). I thought maybe selector is wrong:

```
var id = $(this).prev($('input[name="cat_id"]')).length;
alert(id);
```

Returns 1. Working. 
I just didn't have a clue what' happening and tried

```
var id = $(this).prev($('input[name="cat_id"]')).attr('name');
alert(id);
```

Returns 'undefined'. Strange. Any ideas? Tried prevAll instead of prev, effect is the same. jQuery version is 1.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prev` method takes a selector, not a jQuery object:

```
var id = $(this).prev('input[name="cat_id"]').val();
```

However, just that won't help you in this case. As the selector doesn't match the previous element (the edit link), you will get an empty jQuery object, and `val` won't return the id.

You can use the `siblings` or `prevAll` method to find the element:

```
var id = $(this).siblings('input[name="cat_id"]').val();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("a.delete-link").click(function() {
var id = $(this).prev('input[name="cat_id"]').val();
    alert(id);
});
```

[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

You should pass in selector expression (string) to .prev() method instead of a jQuery object.